# $http post multipart/form-data boundary not set

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, http

I am setting the boundary for the below post call but on chrome the boundary looks different from the one I set. how do I get my custom boundary "--test" to show up on the request payload?

```
    var url = '/site/apkUpload';
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log(formdata);
    $http.post(url, formdata, {
        processData: false,
        headers: {'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data;  charset=utf-8; boundary='--test'",
            'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
            'x-access-token': token,
            'cache-control': 'max-age=0'}
    })
        .success(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        })
        .error(function (reject) {
            deferred.reject(reject);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
```

Request payload on chrome:

------WebKitFormBoundaryB5LjM2a6Qly3Xruj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="packageName"

helo1
------WebKitFormBoundaryB5LjM2a6Qly3Xruj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

......

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quick question aside, why are you creating / returning a promise when $http returns a promis itself ?

Comment: You will probably need to use a transformer. That will let you set the raw value of your request payload as a string. e.g. `$http.post(url, data, {transformRequest: myTransformer})`

Answer (score 0):

I can interpret your question in 2 ways:

1. You are talking about why you are not getting **------WebKitFormBoundaryB5LjM2a6Qly3Xruj** in the POST request header, which you are getting in the request payload. I had the same issue while sending a multi-part formdata using **$http.post** (also I was using [FormData](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header-list)).The solution to this is using **$http(*config*)**.To my understanding *$http.post* underlying uses *$http()* itself to generate XMLHttpRequest object, which should run the *multipart/form-data encoding algorithm* to set the multipart boundary in payload and the header as well. In *$http.post*, it seems whenever you give a custom config object it overwrites the header generated by the algorithm. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726531) answer is also helpful.
2. If you just want to add a custom multipart boundary in the content-header, then you can achieve that by add a tranformRequest function in the config object:

   ```
   var url = '/site/apkUpload';
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   console.log(formdata);
   $http.post(url, formdata, {
       processData: false,
       transformRequest: function (data, headers) {
           var boundary = yourCustomLogic();
           headers()['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data;charset=utf-
           8;boundary=' + boundary;
       },
       'Accept': ...,
       'x-access-token': token,
       'cache-control': 'max-age=0'
   })
   .success( function () {...});
   ```