# How to use AngularJS $http to send multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, http

I am developing a graphical interface that uses different services rest (written in java).
I have to call up a service like this:

```
@PUT
@Path("nomeServizio")
public Response nomeServizio(final FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {
......}
```

Call service:

```
service: function (data) {

            return $http({
                url: PATH_REST_SERVICES + '/nomeServizio',
                headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
                data: data,
                method: "PUT"
            });
        }
```

When I request from my Angularjs service file I get: error 400 (bad request) if the service has a Content-Type = multipart / form-data

While I get a 415 (unsupported media type) error if the service has a Content-Type = "application / x-www-form-urlencoded; charset = utf-8" or "application / json; charset = utf-8" or "application / form-data ".

I am developing the front-end in javascript and html5, I did not find anything in the web that can help me as the FormDataMultiPart object does not exist in javascript.

I tried to format the data to send in many ways but it always returns 400 or 415.

**How should I format the data to send to the rest call?**

**And how should the Content-Type be in the headers?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## How to use AngularJS $http to send FormData

The [FormData interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent using the [XHR Send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) method. It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to `multipart/form-data`.

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('type', type);
formData.append('description', description);
formData.append('photo', photo); 

return $http({
    url: PATH_REST_SERVICES + '/nomeServizio',
    headers: {"Content-Type": undefined },
    data: formData,
    method: "PUT"
});
```

It is important to set the content type header to `undefined`. Normally the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) sets the content type to `application/json`. When the content type is `undefined`, the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) will automatically set the content type to `multipart/form-data` with the proper [multi-part boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data).

Answer (score -1):

in java code you need to write code like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
```

for more you can refer bellow example and link :-

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

Comment: The problem is that I can not change the rest services I use.
I should find a solution that allows me to format (with javascript or php) the data in FormDataMultiPart.