# how can i send the form data with enctype="multipart/form-data" in the post method using $http.post() in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to send the the data of inputs to the server with the post method in angularjs but I want to send the data as the form data. I can send the data as json  data. but I dont know how to send it as a form data. and also I have a input type file so I also want to use enctype multipart/form-data. is there any way?
here is my html

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="username">
    <input type="password" ng-model="password">
    <input type="file" ng-model="photo">
    <button ng-click="submitData"></button>
</form>
```

and here is my js

```
$scope.submitData = function(){
  var data ={
    "username":$scope.username,
    "password":$scope.password,
    "photo":$scope.photo,
  }
  $http.get(url,data).then(function(response){
    $scope.message = response.data;
  });
}
```

here I am sending the data as a json data. But I want to send it as a form data and also I want to use enctype  multipart/form-data. is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FormData](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#formdata) to achieve that.
Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197351/http-post-multipart-form-data-boundary-not-set/47852490#47852490).In your case, you can do

```
$scope.submitData = function(){
  var data = new FormData()
  data.username = $scope.username,;
  data.password = $scope.password;
  data.photo = $scope.photo;
  $http.post(url, formdata, {
    'Content-type': ...,
    'x-access-token': token
  })
  .success( function (response) {...});
}
```

FormData [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: can you please tell me what should I write in the content-type

Comment: sorry for my previous foolish question.  this code is not working for me. I think the reason is photo. When I see the photo in console.log it shows undefined. can you tell me the reason

Comment: take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722093/send-multipart-form-data-files-with-angular-using-http